# How to get the 'page size' option in Google Cloud Platform Stackdriver Logging API to return paged entries with next page token

Tags: php, logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

When I enter a request, via the console test window here:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/list

```
{
  "projectIds": [
    PROJECT_ID
  ],
  "resourceNames": [
    RESOURCE_NAMES
  ],
  "filter": FILTER,
  "orderBy": 'timestamp desc',
  "pageSize": 100
}
```

I set the page size parameter and the correct number of entries are returned along with the next page token. However when I set this option as a parameter to the entries request via the PHP Cloud API, it simply returns non-paginated results; Ignoring the page size limit.

Is this an issue with the php API and has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PATH_TO_JSON_FILE');


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();


$this->loggingClient = new LoggingClient([
    'projectId' => PROJECT_ID
]);

// Get a logger instance.
$logger = $this->loggingClient->logger(LOGGER);

$options = array(
    'pageSize' => 100,
    'orderBy' => 'timestamp desc',
    'filter' => FILTER,
);
$entries = $this->loggingClient->entries($options);
$logs = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
...
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the iterator returned from `LoggingClient::entries()` will paginate for you while you iterate. It is in fact only requesting 100 logs per request to the server, it just is transparent to you :).

If you'd like a quick way to get a page of results at once, we have support for the following as well:

```
$entries = $client->entries([
    'pageSize' => 100
]);

foreach ($entries->iterateByPage() as $page) {
    print count($page); // Should be 100
}
```

Hope this helps!